# C++ Using container as a template type

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

I am trying to supply the underlying container/data structure for a class via template argument. I'd like to have the underlying container always contain a certain pointer type and I want the maximum amount of variable allowed to be stored to be limited, no matter which container is used.

I managed to make something simple work for `std::vector` and `std::array` .
However, for the `std::array` example there are some weird things I have to do so it compiles.

Here is the test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

class CustomVariableIF {
public:
    void getFoo() const {
        std::cout << "Moh!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class CustomVariable: public CustomVariableIF {
public:

    CustomVariable(T initValue): value(initValue) {}

    void setValue(T newValue) {
        value = newValue;
    }

    T getValue() const {
        return value;
    }

private:
    T value = 0;
};

template <typename TContainer>
class CustomVariableSetBase {
public:
    using value_type = typename TContainer::value_type;

    /* This allows std::array, std::vector and std::map as underlying container */
    static_assert(std::is_same<value_type, CustomVariableIF*>::value or
            std::is_same<value_type, std::pair<const uint32_t, CustomVariableIF*>>::value,
            "Invalid template type!");

    CustomVariableSetBase(const size_t maxFillCount): maxFillCount(maxFillCount) {}
    virtual~ CustomVariableSetBase() {};

    template<class Q = TContainer>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename Q::value_type, CustomVariableIF*>::value>::type
    callFoos() {
        size_t currentIdx = 0;
        for (auto& var: container) {
            if(var == nullptr) {
                return;
            }
            if(currentIdx < fillCount) {
                var->getFoo();
                currentIdx++;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Used if underlying container is a std::map */
    template<class Q = TContainer> typename
            std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename Q::value_type,
            std::pair<const uint32_t, CustomVariableIF*>>::value>::type
    callFoos() {
        for (auto& var: container) {
            var.second->getFoo();
        }
    }

protected:

    virtual void registerVariable(CustomVariableIF* variable) = 0;

    TContainer container;
    size_t fillCount = 0;
    const size_t maxFillCount;
};

class CustomVariableMap: public CustomVariableSetBase<std::map<uint32_t, CustomVariableIF*>> {
public:
    CustomVariableMap(const size_t maxVars): CustomVariableSetBase(maxVars) {};
    virtual~ CustomVariableMap() {};

    void registerVariable(CustomVariableIF* variable) override {
        if(fillCount < maxFillCount) {
            container.emplace(idCounter, variable);
            lastId = idCounter;
            idCounter++;
            fillCount++;
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "CustomVariableMap::registerVariable: Map container is full!" << std::endl;
        }
        return;
    }

    uint32_t getIdOfLastAddedVariable() const {
        return lastId;
    }
private:
    uint32_t idCounter = 0;
    uint32_t lastId = 0;

};

class CustomVariableSet: public CustomVariableSetBase<std::vector<CustomVariableIF*>> {
public:
    CustomVariableSet(const size_t maxVars): CustomVariableSetBase(maxVars) {};
    virtual~ CustomVariableSet() {};

    void registerVariable(CustomVariableIF* variable) override {
        if(fillCount < maxFillCount) {
            container.push_back(variable);
            fillCount++;
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "CustomVariableSet::registerVariable: Vector container is full!" <<
                    std::endl;
        }

        return;
    }
private:

};

template <uint8_t NUM_VARIABLES>
class CustomVariableStaticSet:
        public CustomVariableSetBase<std::array<CustomVariableIF*, NUM_VARIABLES>> {
public:
    using ArrayBase = std::array<CustomVariableIF*, NUM_VARIABLES>;
    CustomVariableStaticSet(): CustomVariableSetBase<ArrayBase>(NUM_VARIABLES) {};

    virtual void registerVariable(CustomVariableIF* variable) {
        if(this->fillCount < NUM_VARIABLES) {
            this->container[this->fillCount] = variable;
            this->fillCount++;
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "CustomVariableStaticSet::registerVariable: Array container is full!" <<
                    std::endl;
        }
    }
private:

};


int main() {
    using namespace std;
    CustomVariableSet testSet(2);
    CustomVariableStaticSet<5> testSet2;
    CustomVariableMap testSet3(2);
    CustomVariable<int> someVar1(5);

    testSet.registerVariable(&someVar1);
    testSet.registerVariable(&someVar1);
    std::cout << "Moh! should be printed twice!" << std::endl;
    testSet.callFoos();

    testSet2.registerVariable(&someVar1);
    testSet2.registerVariable(&someVar1);
    std::cout << "Moh! should be printed twice!" << std::endl;
    testSet2.callFoos();

    testSet3.registerVariable(&someVar1);
    testSet3.registerVariable(&someVar1);
    std::cout << "Moh! should be printed twice!" << std::endl;
    testSet3.callFoos();

    std::cout << "Should yield two errors!" << std::endl;
    testSet.registerVariable(&someVar1);
    testSet2.registerVariable(&someVar1);
    testSet3.registerVariable(&someVar1);
}
```

The class which has `std::vector` as the underlying container works like I expected.
For the `std::array` one, I have to write the whole template typename again in the constructor initializer list. I also have to write `this->` everytime I try to access a member of the base class.

Can anyone explain to me why I have to do these steps for the class using `std::array`? Thanks a lot in advance!

Kind Regards
RM

Comment: You need to do this because `CustomVariableStaticSet` is a template, and not because of any idiosyncrasies of `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after some more research I found the more in-depth answer here:

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members
(Question: Why am I getting errors when my template-derived-class uses a member it inherits from its template-base-class?)

A very useful read in general when working with templates. I also updated my test code to include an implementation for `std::map` as the underlying container, which was tricky because the value type is actually different than for the other two containers. There are still some nullptr checks and some other things missing to be really clean, but it worked for me and maybe it can help some other people.